# sed or awk to change a specific number in a file on RHEL7

Tags: sed, sh, redhat

I need help figuring out the syntax or what command to use to find an replace a specific number in a file.
I need to replace the number 10 with 25 in a configuration file. I have tried the following:

`sed 's/10/25/g' /etc/security/limits.conf`

This changes other instances that contain 10 such as 1000 and 10000 to 2500 and 25000, I need to juct change the need to just change 10 to 25. Please help.

Thank you,

Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to limit the `sed` substitution to the line you want to change. For `limits.conf` you are best off matching the domain, type and item. So if you wanted to just change a limit for domain `@student`, type `hard`, item `nproc`, you'd use something like

```
sed '/@student.*hard.*nproc/s/10/25/g' /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Comment: Jon, thank you that was spot on!

Thank you so much for the assist on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ri '/^#/!s/(^.*)([[:space:]]10$)/\1 25/' /etc/security/limits.conf
```

With regular expression interpretation enabled (-r or -E), process all lines that don't start with a # by using ! We then split the lines into two sections, and replace the line for the first section followed by a space and 25. The $ ensure that the entry to replace is anchored at the end of the line.

Awk is another option:

```
awk -i 'NF==4 && $4==10 { gsub("10","25",$4) }1' /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Check if the line has 4 space delimited fields (NF==4) and the 4th field ($4) is 10. If this condition is met, replace 10 with 25 using gsub and print all lines with 1

The -i is an inplace amend flag on more recent versions of awk. If a compliant version is not available, use:

```
awk 'NF==4 && $4==10 { gsub("10","25",$4) }1' /etc/security/limits.conf > /etc/security/limits.tmp && mv -f /etc/security/limits.tmp /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner, where `\b` stands for word break (so that 10 will not match 210 or 102):

```
perl -pe 's/\b10\b/25/g' in_file > out_file
```

Or to change the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\b10\b/25/g' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

The regex uses modifier `/g` : Match the pattern repeatedly.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)